# using a button with a procedural id to save to session storage

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

(i'm not sure procedural is the right word here, but i'm not a native speaker so correct me if it's not)

I have a list of cars from a database and i want each car to have it's own "reserve" button, and i need an id for each button so i can call that specific button in a javascript function so i tried this:

```
 <td><input id="Button+@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.CarID)" type="button" value="Reserve" onclick="Reserve(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.CarID)" /></td>
```

and this for the function:

```
<script>
function Reserve(ID) {
    sessionStorage["ReserveCar"] = ID;
    document.getElementById("Button" + ID).value = "Car Reserved!";
}
</script>
```

why doesn't this work?